# Extract date from a path in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a folder called `files` which has a path like : `C:\users\xxxx\desktop\files`

Inside this folder are different folders: `2015-12-02`, `2015-12-01`, `2015-11-30`, etc

Inside each folder there are multiple files. I was looking to append the folder date at the end of each file inside the folder. I have written the below script for that:

```
function checkfile($file) {
    $filenm = $file.FullName
    return($filenm.Contains('.txt'))
}

function renamefile($file) {
    $filenm = $file.Name
    $ip = $file.FullName.Substring(34)
    $ip1 = $ip.Substring(1,4) + $ip.Substring(6,2) + $ip.Substring(9,2)
    $txt = $filenm.Split(".")[1] + "_" + $file.name.Split(".")[3] + "_" + $file.name.Split(".")[4] + "." + $file.name.Split(".")[2] + "." + $ip1
    Rename-Item $file.FullName -NewName $txt
}

$sourcepath = "C:\users\xxxx\desktop\files"
$inputfiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcepath -Recurse) | Where-Object { checkfile $_ }

foreach ($inputfile in $inputfiles) {
    renamefile $inputfiles
}
```

The problem I'm facing is in the above script I have used `substring(34)` to extract the date from the file path. If for some reason the source path changes (to say : `H:\powershell\scripts\files`) then `34` will not work.

How can I extract the correct date from the file path irrespective of the full file path?

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
$sourcepath = "C:\users\xxxx\desktop\files"

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcepath -Include "*.txt" -Recurse | % {
    Rename-Item $_ "$($_.BaseName)_$($_.Directory)$($_.Extension)"
}
```

`BaseName` is the file name without the extension

`Directory` is the directory name (your date)

`Extension` is the file extension (i.e. `.txt`)

`$(...)` is used to make sure `...` is evaluated properly

`%` is an alias for `ForEach-Object` and will iterate over the objects coming from the pipeline.

`$_` will hold the current object in the `ForEach` loop

Here, your `checkfile` function is replaced by `-Include "*.txt"`.

Example :

```
C:\users\xxxx\desktop\files\2015-12-02\sample.txt
```

becomes

```
C:\users\xxxx\desktop\files\2015-12-02\sample_2015-12-02.txt
```

Not sure if you need it, but if you want to remove the dashes from the date, you could use:

```
Rename-Item $_ "$($_.BaseName)_$($_.Directory -replace '-','')$($_.Extension)"
```

**EDIT :** OP wished to remove the dashes but append the date after the file extension, so:

```
$sourcepath = "C:\users\xxxx\desktop\files"

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcepath -Include "*.txt" -Recurse | % {
    Rename-Item $_ "$($_.Name).$($_.Directory.Name -replace '-', '')"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but i'm not seeing how your are extracting the date (to append at end of file) from the sourcepath which could change. that is being done inside my renamefile function as shown in my script.

Comment: I assumed you wanted to append the directory name (`$_.Directory` here), which is a date in your example. For instance, this would turn `C:\users\xxxx\desktop\files\2015-12-02\sample.txt` into `C:\users\xxxx\desktop\files\2015-12-02\sample_2015-12-02.txt`. This can be adapted, if you specify the format you want as a result better in your question (you can edit it as much as you want).

Comment: Thanks. actually i would like to replace say : C:\users\xxxx\desktop\files\2015-12-02\sample.txt to C:\users\xxxx\desktop\files\2015-12-02\sample.txt.20151202. so from your example can i just do this: Rename-Item $_ "$($_.BaseName)$($_.Extension).$($_.Directory -replace "-","")"

Comment: Exactly, I'll edit my answer accordingly. It can even get simpler.

Comment: Thanks. when i execute the above i'm getting the below error when i save the above in a .ps1 file and execute

Comment: +     Rename-Item $_ "$($_.BaseName)$($_.Extension)$($_.Directory -replace "-","") ...
+                                                                              ~~
The string is missing the terminator: ".
At C:\Users\xxxx\desktop\scpt1.ps1:4 char:81
+ ... replace "-","")"
+                    ~
Missing closing ')' in subexpression.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Comment: sorry, am relatively new to powershell, hence asking many questions.

Comment: Corrected. Since we're already in a double-quoted string, we need to use single quotes with `-replace`. Sorry about this mistake. Also, `$($_.BaseName)$($_.Extension)` is equivalent to `$($_.Name)`

Comment: NP. This time when i execute i'm getting the following

Comment: Rename-Item : Cannot rename because the target specified represents a path or device name
At C:\Users\xxx\desktop\scpt1.ps1:4 char:5
+     Rename-Item $_ "$($_.BaseName)$($_.Extension)$($_.Directory -replace '-','') ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Rename-Item], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: OK sorry again, another mistake. It's corrected, see the last snippet. Now that I have tested it, I know what was wrong : `$_.Directory` holds the complete path to the folder, so the resulting filename was not what we wanted at all ; we need to use `$_.Directory.Name` instead. And the `.` was missing before the date, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked this time. there r still things i'm trying to understand. i see that '$_' stands for current object. how does '$_.Directory.Name' resolve to the date subfolder in the filepath and not to say 'users', 'xxx' or 'desktop'? also why is there a $ before $_.Name and $_.Directory.Name ? sorry, am still exploring and want to thoroughly understand what i'm doing.

Comment: oh i see now, is it because '2015-12-01' is the last folder in the path and since we're providing the full source path: C:\users\xxx\desktop\files it know that the next directory level is the date folder '2015-12-01'. if the source was say : C:\users\xxx\desktop\2015-12-01\files then this would not work right?

Comment: _$(...) is used to make sure ... is evaluated properly_ : without it only `$_` would be interpreted in `$_.Directory.Name`. As for your other question you got it totally right :) some info about the cookie jar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429992/how-to-accept-an-answer-to-my-post - if you have other questions, shoot ^^

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score -1):

The particulars of the problem aren't entirely clear. I gather that the date your are interested in is in the fullpath. You want to extract the date from the path and rename the file, such that the new filename includes that date at the end.

However your script implies that there are at least five periods in the path. But I don't see that mentioned in the OP anywhere.

So there are a few problems and open items I see:
1. What is the syntax of a full path? That includes the five or more periods
2. Will the date always be at the same directory depth? I'm guessing xxxx represents the date. If so the date is the second subdirectory. Will the date always be in the second subdirectory?
3. Related to #2, will there ever be paths that include two or more dates?

Assuming my guesses are correct AND that the date will always be the second subdirectory, then extracting the date would be:

```
`$dateString = $file.fullpath.split('\')[3]
```

If some of my guesses are incorrect then please add details to the OP. If #3 is true then you'll need to also explain how to know which date is the correct date to use.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The syntax for the full path is : "C:\users\<mysystemusername>\desktop\files\2015-12-01" and so forth (for each date folder) inside this folder there are files which i'm renaming them by splitting the name using periods and constructing the correct filename. this part if working. the only issue i'm facing is how to extract the date like in this is case 2015-12-01 and append to the file name. the date will not be in same directory depth because the part "C:\users\<mysystemusername>\desktop\files" can change. the xxxx in the filepath is <mysystemusername>.

Comment: And yes, the date will always be in the second subdirectory and will occur only once.

Comment: so i was wondering is there is a way to extract the date from the path using regex and then get the indexof that and use it in the substring function. that way whatever be the path name, the date can always be extracted using regex. the indexof that can be fed to the substring function to extract the date. something like that. not very sure if that approach sounds good.

Comment: Based on your first comment the date will be the fifth subdirectory in the path. Not the second. RE: third comment, yes you can use REGEX. In fact you'll get the matched expression in $matches if you specify a sub-expression (`help about_Regular_Expressions`) so you won't need to use substring().

Answer (score -1):

An option that you could do is just `cd` to each path. Then use `Get-ChildItem` in each dir, without using `-Recurse`.

In rename `$ip` would just be `$file`, no need for `FullName`.

For example, define your functions and then:

```
$sourcefile = 'Whateversourcediris'
cd $sourcefile
$directories = (Get-ChildItem)
foreach ($direct in $directories) {
    cd $direct
    $inputfiles = (Get-ChildItem)|where-object{checkfile $_}
    foreach ($inputfile in $inputfiles) {
        renamefile $inputfile
    }
    cd..
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. your approach looks good, but i dont see in this how your are extracting the date (to append at end of file) from the sourcepath which could change. that is being done inside my renamefile function as shown in my script.

Comment: He didn't reproduce the function declaration, but he used `renamefile` (in the last `foreach` loop)